# array name from variable in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, variables

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int positionsecond, long id)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    if(spinner.getId() == R.id.rountinespinner2)
    {
        String mDrawableName =Biceps[positionsecond].toLowerCase();//in this part i need the "Biceps"[postionsecond] as variable[positionsecond] .
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        rountinesdisplayer.setImageResource(resID);
    }
}
```

1. i have arrays  as

   `String[] Biceps = {"Dumbell_curls", "Hammer_curl", "concentration_curls"};`

   `String[]Triceps={"tricep_ext", "lying_triceps_ext", ,"diamond_push_ups" };`

   `String[] Shoulders = {"front_arm raises","lateral_arm_raises"  };`

   2. i am Getting Biceps, Triceps and Shoulders value in a String a (eg:-     a="Biceps";)

   now for getting values i use:-
    `Biceps[0]`

   `Biceps[1]` etc.

   i want to get value like
   Suppose my Variable a has got value  `String a= "Biceps";` 
       i would like `a[0]` be like `Biceps[0];`
   such that ill get value as Dumbell Curls in this case
   i want the Biceps value from the variable "a" --> like `a[0]="Dumbell Curls";`

   Similarly if `a="Triceps";`
   Normally i have to use `Triceps[0];`
   but i want it to be `a[0];`

   So that of Complexity can be avoided in my code

   Would be Great Help ....
   Please Help me ......

Comment: Can you explain the question more clearly. It is still not clear. I would be happy to help.

Comment: It's unclear what it is you are actually trying to do. It's easy to test your string `a` to see which type it is, but you can't suddenly copy a String array to a String and call things like `a[0], a[1], ...` etc. So you've either got a design problem, or you don't understand the fundamentals of Strings versus String arrays. So more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Sir, i want to use it like triceps[0] = a[0]; when a = triceps; i mean instead of using it from triceps[0] , biceps[0] , Shoulders[0];  if i have the value of a="triceps" then can i use it like a[0] and get the value;

Comment: i Hope you Understand Sir, is it Possible to Fetch an array by using a  variable that has the array name stored in it and fetch it .

Comment: I don't see why you would have to reference your arrays in that manner.  But one option is to create a method that transverses an array and pass it the array that you need to use.

Comment: can you tell  me how to implement that??